# Error en colMeans(x, na.rm = TRUE), escalando datos en R

Tags: r, csv, cluster, plot, scale

Estoy intentando agrupar un siguiente conjunto de datos de un archivo que tengo en  = 2, 4, 6, 8, 10 grupos, son estos los datos
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

así que decidí escalar los datos quitando las 4 primeras columnas que no son de datos númericos de esta forma : df <- scale(data[,-4])
pero me da error, alguien sabe cómo arreglarlo? Error in colMeans(x, na.rm = TRUE) : 'x' debe ser numérico

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Edito en base a lo que me respondiste:

El problema radica en que solo estas quitando la columna 4, dejando las primeras 3 que no son numéricas, prueba con esto:

```
df <- scale(data[-(1:4)])
```

Otra forma muy practica seria utilizar lo siguiente:

```
df %>%
  mutate_if(is.numeric, scale)
```

Es decir, a todas las variables de tu df, si son numéricas, que aplique la función scale